# "Disk driver for / is not ready yet or not present" error after upgrade

Tags: 11.04, boot-failure

I tried to upgrade my Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. After total upgrade, when I reboot my laptop I got following error :

```
Init: udevtrigger main process (531) terminated with status 1
Init: udevtrigger Post-stop (548) terminated with status 1
Init: udevmonitor main process (530) killed by TERM signal
The disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present
Continue to wait; or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons this could have occurred.  Please see the link below for a solution.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1507558